# Is there a gcc warning for non-multithreaded native C functions?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, obsolete

When you have a C program that uses known non-multithreaded functions such as `strtok`, `ctime`... is there a compiler (gcc, clang, icc...) option to trigger a warning, possibly reminding you to use `strtok_r`, `ctime_r`, etc...? Maybe something to do with the way the compiler deals with obsolete functions ? It would be more accurate than to `grep` the source code.

Comment: I'd check the runtime documentation: Those functions can be implemented in a thread-safe way. They aren't reentrant then, which is a different issue, but simply use thread-local storage.

Comment: Yes, I could have phrased it better. Reentrant functions are normally safe in multithreaded programs as long as your don't share their arguments between threads !